# Best way to use an autoencoder with any classifier in keras

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, classification, batch-processing

I built and trained a autoencoder in Keras, removed the decoder part and add a flatten layer in order to produce a feature vector.

Now I wish to train a classifier (SVM for example) but, as preprocess step I need to apply the encoder to get the feature vector which will be used in the classifier.

The problem is, the whole dataset does not fit into the memory! To overcome this during the training of the autoencoder I created a generator and used the `fit_generator(..)` function of the `Model`.

Thus, I'm stuck in the same situation to train the SVM. I read about [Pipelines](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) in sk-learn, but I'm not sure if it will work for my situation, since I have the batch situation. I also read about the [scaling stategies](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html) recommended in sk-learn doc page but again, run partial fit is not a problem, the real problem is the preprocess step which have to run in batches as well.

I would like to know which are the strategies that I can used in this situation?

Comment: But you are already using `fit_generator()` in pre-processing step, aren't you? Please explain more clearly what do you want?

Comment: in general lines: I need to train a SVM with a pre-process step which is an encoder. Also, I need to run both in batches.